# Compare() method, Parent and Children objects sorting not perfect

Tags: c#, arrays, compare, icomparable

I have this homework. And I am beginner C# program, and now learn the C# and Java

*Homework:* Write static method that get a Drink[] array, where the AlcoholDrink has got different alcohol values. The method returns an array containing the three highest alcohol value! If it is not so much AlcoholDrink in the array, the method is returning a null reference!

I have tried write this method, but it not work correctly...

Cause at the  *sz[1] = (AlcoholDrink)t[1];* it is a Drink object (non-alcohol), I don't understand why it is there...

Or maybe my Compare method is not perfect, maybe there is the mistake... How can I aim, the non AlcoholDrink objects (Drink Objects) go to the end of the array?

Here my C# code:

```
    class DrinkComparer : IComparer<Drink>
    {
        public int Compare(Drink x, Drink y)
        {
            // AlcoholDrink class is children of Drink class
            if (x is AlcoholDrink && y is AlcoholDrink)
            {
                AlcoholDrink a = (AlcoholDrink)x;
                AlcoholDrink b = (AlcoholDrink)y;
                double aAlk = a.GetValueOfAlcohol; 
                double bAlk = b.GetValueOfAlcohol;
                if (aAlk > bAlk)
                    return -1;
                else if (aAlk < bAlk)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            // Drink objects haven't got GetValueOfAlcohol method...
            // How can I aim, the non AlcoholDrink objects (Drink objects) go to the end     array?
            else
                return 1;                
        }
    }
    static AlcoholDrink[] Largest3AlcoholDrink(Drink[] t)
    {
        Array.Sort(t, new DrinkComparer());
        AlcoholDrink[] sz = new AlcoholDrink[3];
        sz[0] = (AlcoholDrink)t[0];
        sz[1] = (AlcoholDrink)t[1];
        sz[2] = (AlcoholDrink)t[2];
        return sz;
    }
        AlcoholDrink sz = new AlcoholDrink( "Kékfrankos" , "0.75 l", 1500, 4.5);
        Console.WriteLine(sz);

        Drink[] t = new Drink[8];
        t[0] = new AlcoholDrink("Kék Portói", "0.75 l", 1200, 20.5);
        t[1] = new Drink("Tocsik", "0.75 l", 1100); // Non Alcohol Drink
        t[2] = new AlcoholDrink("Tokaji Asszú", "0.75 l ", 1600, 14.5);
        t[3] = new AlcoholDrink("Egri Bikavér", "0.75 l", 1500, 23.5);
        t[4] = new Drink("Egri Szamóca", "0.75 l", 1100); // Non Alchol Drink
        t[5] = new AlcoholDrink("Egri Merlot", "0.75 l", 1700, 18.5);
        t[6] = new AlcoholDrink("Egri Medina", "0.75 l", 900, 16.5);
        t[7] = new AlcoholDrink("Törley Talisman", "0.75 l", 750, 4.5);
        Console.WriteLine(DrinkKeres( t, "Egri Bikavér"));

        Largest3AlcoholDrink(t);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: it would be much simpler if the base class has GetValueOfAlcohol method so the nonalchhole objects  would have 0  from this method.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the prof said, musn't implement GetValueOfAlcohol method or valueOfAlcohol field in the base class

Comment: What about if only one of the params of `Compare(Drink x, Drink y)` is AlcoholDrink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
        // Drink objects haven't got GetValueOfAlcohol method...
        // How can I aim, the non AlcoholDrink objects (Drink objects) go to the end     array?
        else
            return 1;
```

You want non alcoholic drinks to go the end, but this will return 1 even if one of the drinks is alcoholic.  Do this:

```
else if (x is AlcoholicDrink) return -1;
else if (y is AlcoholicDrink) return 1;
else return 0;
```

Comment: by the way of OP's ordering (descending) you should change your plus minus locations.

Comment: Yes-yes, this work and this is the best, thank you very much, but the logic is not clear for me the else if cases ... The simple compare method is ok, but this, why :D. Maybe I am going to sleep and tomorrwo I will understand :)

Comment: The logic is explained in my answer; it handles the four cases separately as I suggested.  The conditions in the latter "if" statements don't have to test both x and y because you already know that (x is AlcoholDrink && y is AlcoholDrink) is false.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the sort function calls your compare method with a normal Drink and an AlcoholDrink.  You return 1, which is good because Drink > AlcoholDrink.  However if your Compare method is called with an AlcoholDrink and a normal Drink you also return 1, which is bad because AlcoholDrink is not greater than Drink.

You need to explicitly handle the four separate cases (AlcoholDrink,AlcoholDrink); (AlcoholDrink,Drink); (Drink, AlcoholDrink) and (Drink, Drink) and return appropriate values for each one.

Comment: Yes but it will be to long time to implement

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the non-alcoholic drinks to go to the end of the array? Could you filter them out instead?

If LINQ is a possibility for you, you could use `t.OfType<AlcoholDrink>()` to do the filtering. Otherwise, you could implement your own method:

```
public AlcoholDrink[] GetAlcoholicDrinks(Drink[] drinks) {
  ArrayList alcoholDrinks = new ArrayList();
  foreach (Drink drink in drinks) {
    if (drink is AlcoholDrink) {
      alcoholDrinks.Add(drink);
    }
  }
  return alcoholDrinks.ToArray(typeof(AlcoholDrink)) as AlcoholDrink[];
}
```

Comment: It's a homework assignment, the point of which is learning to implement IComparable. This would work, but is outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: I don't agree. `IComparable` is still needed to sort the drinks by alcoholic content.